# how do i access a JSONArray of this structure in android

Tags: android, json

Hello guys i am still finding my feet in android and json and am finding difficulties accessing a json structure of this form.

Below is a portion of the json array i want to access in my json array file am using

```
"Topics": [
"ABIRABƆ",
"PƐYƐ",
"KASAKOA",
"DODOƆ KABEA",
"EDIN",
"EDIN NKYERƐKYERƐMU",
"EDINNSIANANMU",
"ADEYƐ",
"ƆKYERƐFOƆ",
"NKABOMDEƐ",
"NTAMGYINAFOƆ"
 ],
```

where i want to get the values all the values under **"Topics"**

Will appreciate the help thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
{"Topics": [
    "ABIRABƆ",
    "PƐYƐ",
    "KASAKOA",
    "DODOƆ KABEA",
    "EDIN",
    "EDIN NKYERƐKYERƐMU",
    "EDINNSIANANMU",
    "ADEYƐ",
    "ƆKYERƐFOƆ",
    "NKABOMDEƐ",
    "NTAMGYINAFOƆ"
]}

JSONObject jso = getCodeAboveAsJSONObject(); //however you wish to do that.
JSONArray topics = jso.getJSONArray("Topics");

for (int i = 0; i < topics.length(); i++) {
    String s = topics.getString(i);
    // do something with String s
}
```